# Reboot CentOS serveer from PHP ? (not php service but the server)

Tags: php, centos

I'm currently working on an appliance and trying to grant the user the possibility to restart the server which host it.

Would there be any way to give apache the right to do it ?

I've tried, when clicking on a submit button, to execute this code :

```
<?php exec('/sbin/reboot'); ?>
```

But it says that only root can do it.

So, I tried adding this in the sudoers file :

```
nobody ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

And I still got this error which prevent me from rebooting the server from PHP.

The role php is using is apache.

I've also tried using `shutdown -r` now and got the same issue.

Would there be any way to do this ? I've seen several systems which allows that but I don't find how they do so...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not really familiar with what you're doing, but I do notice this:

You say:

`nobody ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot`

...

`The role php is using is apache.`

So shouldn't you say in sudoers file:

**`apache`**`ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot`

Comment: Hum yeah you are right, I changed it. Problem is that nothing happens and that the execution shows no output, though it actually creates the output file...

Comment: @user2377141 What do you mean 'it actually creates the output file' ? Where does it create a file, and what is then in that file?

Comment: @user2377141 Also: you are granting the right to run /sbin/reboot. But reboot is just a script running `shutdown -r now` if I'm not mistaking. Try also grating the right to run shutdown (is it also in /sbin/ ?)

Comment: Well it creates the outputfile I asked him to create at the location I asked but it is empty while it should say "Need to be root" in case it doesn't work, which happens.
I tried granting apache the right to run shutdown but still nothign happens.

Comment: @user2377141 anything in /var/log/messages ?